# Use only css transform translate to control animation instead of margin and other non-optimization

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to recreate this animation using using transform translate properties. The animation use margin to control the animation and that is not optimize. It can cause stutter. How would you accomplish that using transform translate?

He is the original source of the code: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Mark_Bowley/pen/mEtqj)

```
<style>
body {
    background: #00b4ff;
    color: #333;
    font: 100% Lato, Arial, Sans Serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#background-wrap {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* KEYFRAMES */

@-webkit-keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        margin-top: 1000px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top: -100%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

@keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

/* ANIMATIONS */

.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: -5%;
    top: 5%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x2 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 5%;
    top: 80%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x3 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 10%;
    top: 40%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}

.x4 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 20%;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x5 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 30%;
    top: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}

.x6 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 50%;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

.x7 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 65%;
    top: 70%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
    transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x8 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 80%;
    top: 10%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x9 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 90%;
    top: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x10 {
    -webkit-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;

    left: 80%;
    top: 80%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
    transform: scale(0.3);
}

/* OBJECTS */

.bubble {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

.bubble:after {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), color-stop(70%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);

    content: "";
    height: 180px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
}
</style>
<div id="background-wrap">
    <div class="bubble x1"></div>
    <div class="bubble x2"></div>
    <div class="bubble x3"></div>
    <div class="bubble x4"></div>
    <div class="bubble x5"></div>
    <div class="bubble x6"></div>
    <div class="bubble x7"></div>
    <div class="bubble x8"></div>
    <div class="bubble x9"></div>
    <div class="bubble x10"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following keyframe code in your css. Make sure to prefix the keyframes and the transform property as well.

```
.bubble {
    margin-top: 1000px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

@keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-2000px);
    }
}

@keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
}
```

Comment: WRONG! The code you listed will not work cause of css overwrite transform properties set. Plus I already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a choice made about transform and how they work without thinking about having transform defined by the properties you can set on it and not having the properties only be set on one define transform on that element. I was hoping of someone showing me the same effect as the code in the pin with the motion. You can use the following keyframe code in your css to get the bubble to move up and swing side to side but getting that smooth motion like you see is another story.

```
@keyframes animateBubble {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0px -50vh);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(5px 100vh);
    }
}
```